# Do I use 'was' or 'did' as an auxiliary in an interrogative clause?

Tags: word-choice, past-tense, auxiliary-verbs, interrogatives

Which is correct?

> Was the cheese taste delicious?

or

> Did the cheese taste delicious?

I know that we should use 'did' when we want to ask some question in the past simple form, but I'm not sure about this case. When we use "did" in this sentence, it sounds like supposition about cheese taste, but I need to ask straightly.

How to say it correctly?

Comment: Here's a simple rule: we use *to be* (*is, was, were*, etc.) in the question when the original statement used *to be*.  We use *to do* (*do, does, did*, etc.) when the original statement used any other verb.  So for example: She is tall. / *Is* she tall?  The fire burned. / *Did* the fire burn?  In your case, the verb is *taste*, so we have to use *to do* in the question.

Comment: @stangdon Well, we do not always use *to do* in the absence of *to be*. Have you never heard that? Must I give examples?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen - I said it was a simple rule, not an all-comprehensive rule covering every single situation.  Feel free to give examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR; You should use "did", because your main verb is preceded by no auxiliaries.

There's a phenomenon in questions called 'subject–auxiliary inversion'.

You already probably know what a subject is; it's "Max" in "Max had lunch in a restaurant." 'auxiliary' is a type of verb, but not the normal type. You're familiar with auxiliaries as well; one such example is "was" in "It was raining very heavily yesterday." Auxiliary verbs are verbs, but they somehow **assist** the other verbs in the sentence they appear.

So, what does 'subject–auxiliary inversion' mean? It means that, to form a question, you simply need to swap the places of the subject and the auxiliary:

> **It** *was* raining very heavily yesterday.

becomes

> *Was* **it**  raining very heavily yesterday?

So the question becomes "which auxiliary should I use?" To answer, you need to remind yourself of what the verb phrase in the declarative sentence is. If there's a "be" verb in the initial sentence, you simply swap the place of subject and the auxiliary, and add a question mark, to create an interrogative sentence.

> **Kim** *was* creating a warm and welcoming atmosphere for all the strangers.

becomes

> *Was* **Kim**  creating a warm and welcoming atmosphere for all the strangers?

In cases where "be" is a main verb, you can apply the same process.

> Kim was happy.

becomes

> Was Kim happy?

If, however, there are no auxiliary or main "be"s present, you create an interrogative sentence (question) by using "did" as auxiliary.

> I tried to fly with metal wings.

becomes

> **Did** I *try* to fly with metal wings?

Notice how "try" is in the plain form, without any suffix or prefixes. Any changes are done to the auxiliary "did".

In your sentence, you need to examine what the initial sentence was. Was it

> *It was taste delicious.

or

> It tasted delicious.

? You already know that if you use an auxiliary "was" before a main verb in a sentence, you need to use the main verb in the gerund form. "I was try" is ungrammatical while "I was trying" is grammatical, albeit incomplete.

---

As the comment by Ilmari points out below, you may also encounter constructions such as these:

> I **did** convince him to buy us a new laptop.
>   He **does** seem inclined to eat junk food.

So, what's the deal with these? They have an auxiliary, but it's not one of "be"'s forms. It's called an [emphatic 'do'](http://grammar.about.com/od/e/g/Emphatic-do.htm). As you may have guessed, just like the case of "was", you can simply swap (or inverse) the auxiliary and the subject to create an interrogative.

> **Did** *I* convince him to buy us a new laptop?
>   **Does** *he* seem inclined to eat junk food?

Comment: It might be useful to note that "I did try to fly" is also grammatical, and basically a more emphatic (but otherwise equivalent) way of saying "I tried to fly".

Comment: I kept thinking something was missing. :)

Answer (score 10):

Because you're using "taste", you need to use "did".

> Did the cheese taste delicious?

However, if you omit "taste", you would use "was". I would argue that this form is much more common because, in general, "taste" is implied with "delicious".

> Was the cheese delicious?

The former would be more (or at least equally) common if you used just about any word other than "delicious":

> Did the cheese taste [salty/sweet/sour/good...]?

versus

> Was the cheese [salty/sweet/sour/good]?

Both of these are pretty equal in my mind, though the version with "taste" is a bit more specific.

Comment: I mean, can't we make the compound word "cheese taste" like 'the car door', 'the kitchen window', etc.? With 'taste' meaning " the sweet, sour, bitter, or salty quality of a thing that you can sense when it is in your mouth"

Comment: @Lambie We would normally say "The cheese tasted awful".

Comment: This is not a compound word I recommend you use... You should be extremely cautious making compound words because most of them won't work. We tend to only use them in specific situations and this isn't one of them.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54015/discussion-on-answer-by-catija-do-i-use-was-or-did-as-an-auxiliary-in-an-int).